# How come I can see nothing about the ecommerce from the Google Analytics admin site

Tags: google-analytics

Here's the script for tracking the ecommerce on my site, http://gist.github.com/452437 , I tried to do the purchase for several times, but I don't anything happened on https://www.google.com/analytics/reporting/ecommerce , I double checked the script for several times and I can't see anything wrong, could somebody help to point out what the problem is? Thanks a lot

Comment: How long did you wait before checking? Google Analytics only updates every 24 hours (IIRC).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked the results about 1 hours after I've done the purchase, are you sure it's updated every 24 hours?

Comment: @Erik, there's nothing in the Ecommerce page until now

Comment: Your production code doesn't have the missing >';< on line 17?

Comment: @Jamie, thanks for pointing out the typo, it's only in the gist, in my production code, it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's deal with the easy case first--**have you designated the Site as an Ecommerce Site from the GA Admin Interface** (the default setting is "no")?

(Obviously, you can ignore the first few lines here if you only have a single GA Account and a single Profile under that Account.)

Login to GA, then select the Account from the menu in the upper right-hand corner, then select the Profile from the menu to the left.

The next page will show you a list of Reports from the Profile you selected. Find the one you want, and click "Edit", which is at the far right on the same line as the Report you chose.

The page you'll see now has a section called ***Main WebSite Profile Information*** (on a line with a grey background). This section contains two columns, which are keys (column 1) and values (column 2) of the Profile Information.

The sixth row in the first column is ***Ecommerce Website***. Check the value (column 2, row six)--is it "No"?

If it is then click "Edit" to the right and on the same line as *WebSite Profile Information*.

The third item down is "Ecommerce Website" below which are two radio buttons--check "Yes, an Ecommerce Site"

Then click "Save Changes" at the bottom left of that page.

Cause some Ecommerce activity--anything that will show up in the GA Browser, then wait four hours for the GA Server to update and see if it's there.

Comment: thanks a lot for providing such detailed steps. Sadly, I've done that beforehand, the radio button has already been checked.